# Verify which numbers are prime in the list

Tags: python, loops, iteration, primes

I am trying to verify which numbers in the list are primes.

```
vetor = [2,3,4,5,11,15,20]
divisions_list = []

def isprime():                     
    divisions = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(1, vetor[i+1]):
        if i % i == 0:
            divisions = divisions + 1
            divisions_list.append(divisions)
        if divisions == 2:
            print('The number {} is prime'.format(vetor[i]))
        else:
            print('The number {} is not prime'.format(vetor[i]))

print(isprime())
```

But this doesn't work, I'm only receiving:

> The number 3 is not prime The number 4 is prime None

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you ask a python question about an error, you need to post the entire traceback since it has important information to help solve your problem. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Seems like you're using the variable `i` twice on accident. Try naming the other `j`.

Answer (score 2):

You already had a piece of code that takes a number and checks if it is a prime or not, then instead of using it you reinvented the wheel and broke it in the process (for example, you re-used `i` which caused a division by zero and tried to check if a list is equal to 2 instead of checking if its length is 2).

Use a function to reuse the working code with some improvements:

- You don't really care how many numbers divide the number you check. It is enough that one number divides it in order for that number to not be prime
- We can start the division check from 2, and it is proven mathematically that it is enough to go up to the square root of the number

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):  
        if n % i == 0:       
            return False
    return True
```

Then use it with the list of numbers:

```
vector= [2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 15, 20]

for n in vector:
    if is_prime(n):
        print(n, 'is a prime')
    else:
        print(n, 'is not a prime')
```

Outputs

```
2 is a prime
3 is a prime
4 is not a prime
5 is a prime
11 is a prime
15 is not a prime
20 is not a prime
```

Comment: I am trying to count how many times the number is divisible, because if it is more than 2, the number is not prime, following the thinking of 'prime number has only two divisions...' Also, your code is saying the number 4 is prime

Comment: @carol I understand that. The point is that you should not care if a number is divisible by 3 numbers or 4 numbers in order to determine if it is prime. It is enough that the number is divisible by **a** number which is not itself or 1 (which is why we start from 2 and end at the square root of it) for us to announce that it is prime. Regarding 4, see the update code. It's important to use `int(sqrt(n)) + 1` as the upper limit for `range` (since it is exclusive at the end).

Comment: Yes, now works. I've watched a video on youtube showing that logic for primes and I thought it was a good one for learning to solve list of prime numbers... Apparently is not... Thank you!

Comment: This code incorrectly claims that 0 and 1 are primes.  For double the efficiency, have  `is_prime()` handle less than 2, 2 itself, and even numbers as special cases at the beginning of the function and start looping from 3 over only the odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

max divisor of an integer x, is sure x//2 and not sqr(x) and not sqrt(x)+1 , this is mathematics

For example x=16, sqrt(x)=4, sqr(x)+1=5
But max divisor of 16 is 8 (really 16//2)

```
"""
verify prime or not in a list of number
"""

# my function :) 
def isPrime(x):
    """
    function get an integer as argument, and return True if this argument is prime and False if not
    """
    i = 2
    while i<=x//2 :
        if x%i != 0:
            i += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True 


# your code :) 
vetor = [2,3,4,5,11,15,20]

# for all elements e in vetor
for e in vetor:
    # test the return of isPrime function applied to arg e
    if isPrime(e):
        print("{} is prime number".format(e))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime number".format(e))
```

Comment: max divisor of an integer x, is sure x//2 and not sqr(x) and not sqr(x)+1 , this is mathematics, for example x=16, sqr(x) =4 but max divisor of 16 is 8 (really 16/2)

Comment: This code incorrectly claims that 0 and 1 are primes.  The expression `i<=x//2` works but is not optimal.  A common expression for it is `i * i <= x`.  For every divisor above the square root, there's one below -- we only need check the divisors below and the square root itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is simpler than you're trying to make it.  You have most of the pieces you need but we need to add a couple of things, toss a bunch of stuff, and rearrange a bit:

```
vetor = [2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 15, 20]

def isprime():
    for number in vetor:
        if number < 2:
            print('The number {} is not prime'.format(number))
            continue

        i = 2

        while i * i <= number:
            if number % i == 0:
                print('The number {} is not prime'.format(number))
                break

            i += 1
        else:  # no break
            print('The number {} is prime'.format(number))

isprime()
```

Much of the additional code that other answers include is about efficiency and there's lots to be learned.  But the above is sufficient for the code to work.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
The number 2 is prime
The number 3 is prime
The number 4 is not prime
The number 5 is prime
The number 11 is prime
The number 15 is not prime
The number 20 is not prime
>
```

My favorite number to include in a prime test is 25 as using `<` instead of `<=` tends to turn it into a prime!